# Check multiple files exist in directory

Tags: file, unix, testing

How to find multiple files present in a directory in `ksh` (on`AIX`)

I am trying below one:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ];then
    echo "Please enter the path"
    exit
fi
path=$1
if [ [ ! f $path/cc*.csv ] && [ ! f $path/cc*.rpt ] && [ ! f $path/*.xls ] ];then
    echo "All required files are not present\n"
fi
```

I am getting error like `check[6]: !: unknown test operator` //check is my file name.

what is wrong in my script. Could someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simplest idea:

```
N=$(ls -1 *mask* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
echo $N
```